# I have a dot bouncing around an image. Need to calculate angles of reflection off of groups of pixels (surface of objects)

Tags: c, animation, image-processing, geometry, artificial-intelligence

Suppose we have an image (pixel buffer) that is in black and white, so each pixel is either black or white (not gray scale).

Now somewhere in the middle of that images, place a green dot. It may have a radius of n for rendering purposed, but it is really a just point. Give the dot a randomly selected direction and speed, and start it moving. If the image is all white pixels, the dot will bounce off the edges of the image, infinitely wandering around the picture. This is quite easy... just reverse either the rise or run of the dot's vector.

Next, suppose the image has some globs of black pixels. As the dot encounters these globs of black pixels, the angle of reflection needs to be calculated. This is also quite easy of the the black pixels have a fixed slope, as in my sketch (blue X represents black pixels). You can find the slope of the blue Xs and easily calculate the new vector.

But how about the case where the black pixels form really unfriendly surfaces? What are some approaches to figuring out this angle?

[image]

This is the subject that I am interested in.

There must be some algorithms that exist for this kind of purpose, but I never ran across any in school. I am not asking how to code this, rather approaches to writing the algorithm to do this. I have a few ideas that I'll try, but if there are some standard ways to do this that exist, I'd like to learn about them.

Obviously I'd like to start with Black and White then move into RGBA.

I am looking for any reference material on just this sort of subject. Websites, books, or other references are very very welcome.

Also, if there are different StackOverflow tags that could be good, let me know.

Thanks much!

Edit********** More pics and information

Maybe I wasn't clear what I meant by "unfriendly surfaces". In the previous picture, our blue X's happened to just be a line. Picture a case where it is not a line, rather a wierd shape.

We start with our green pixel traveling at a slope of 2. Suppose it's vector is that of 12 pixels per frame. It would have a projected path like this:
[image]

But suppose instead of a nice friendly line, we have this:
[image]

In my mind I can kinda of see what is likely to happen if this were a ball and some walls.

Comment: so you need to calculate the tangent to the black blob at the point of impact and reflect off it. I don't see the problem. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I think Roger is correct. Can you define what you mean by "really unfriendly surfaces"?  Any surface I could think of is till just a single point of contact to the tangent of the blobs surface.

Comment: Sure, I've added more pics and a little more text to the original. In the case of the final picture, we are not presented with a simple line to reflect off of, rather we must calculate the slope. I'm sure I can throw some code together to get this done by analizng the pixels around where the dot's path changes from white pixels to black, but I was just wondering if there are any algorithms for this occasion instead of home brewing one.

Answer (score 2):

Look for edge detection algorithms used in image processing. Some edge detectors also approximate the direction of edges.

You can think of the pixel neighborhood of the green dot, maybe somewhere between 3x3 and 7x7, as a small edge direction detection problem.  One approach would take two passes at the pixels:

1. In the first pass, smooth the sharp black/white pixels using a [Gaussian filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter).
2. In the second pass, apply an edge detection operator, such as [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), [Prewitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt) or [Roberts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_Cross) to produce the X and Y derivatives of the pixels' intensity. You can then approximate the direction as:

   `angle = arctan(dx/dy)`

The motivation for the smoothing pass is to give the edge detection operator information from farther-away pixels.

The Wikipedia page on the [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Stages_of_the_Canny_algorithm) has a good discussion on obtaining the direction (the "gradient") of an edge, including an example of a particular Gaussian filter you can use for smoothing.

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of information I was hoping to discuss. I'll read into your suggestions and links. I'm already using arctan to get the angle of my dot's vector, as it's created with a flick gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Am doing something similar with a ball and randomly generated backgrounds.

The filter and edge detection is highly technical but all other processes using a 5*5 or 3*3 grid seem similarly difficult.

However, I think I may have a cheap way around this. Assuming a ball travelling in any direction, scan all leading edges of the ball - a semicircle. The further to the edge of the ball the collision occurs the closer to vertical is the collision. Again, I think, this should allow you to easily infer the background normal and from there the answer is fairly simple